# Is it unethical to add same environmental data such as temperature and salinity in two different papers?

Tags: journals, peer-review

I have collected sea water samples from a location to study the microbes. The study is basically divided into 2; one is considering the total community and another one is specific to a particular groups. If I write 2 papers considering these two matters, can I use the same physico-chemical properties?

Comment: Try to read this article [Maximizing Your Data or Data Slicing? Recommendations for Managing Multiple Submissions from the Same Dataset](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1740-8784.2011.00228.x/full).

Comment: @Kayan Would you please explain why this question has anything to do with peer review?

Answer (score 3):

Researchers frequently have to decide how to publish journal articles from a large data set. When it is not possible to write a single, integrative article from such a data set, the issue of publishing multiple journal articles arises. [Here is good article about the issue](https://libres.uncg.edu/ir/uncg/f/M_Fine_Publishing_1994.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is not unethical if you are asking a different question, and thus, analysing the data in a different way. If the publication re-uses data that was previously published/submitted elsewhere you will need to be clear about that in your manuscript and possibly the cover letter/email to the editor. Depending on the journal, you could simply reference the previous manuscript rather than re-publish the data in tables/figures. In this case, the second article might fit the style of a short communication/letter. But it would be preferable if you include some novel data in each manuscript, which seems to be the case (i.e. additional community members in one of the articles).

It is important to recognise that each journal (and even editors within the journal) will have a different preference on this matter (see the article provided in a comment by `user3624251`). Make sure you revise the journal requirements and potentially contact the editor prior to submitting to inquire on their policy.